# Adding new jqPlot charts to div dynamically makes the old ones empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, jqplot

I have a div (overflow: auto) to which I dynamically add inner divs after a certain period. When a new one is added, it is added to the beginning. Each one of the inner divs have a jqPlot chart, and as long as there is just one it works fine, but as soon as another div is added two things happen with the old one(s):

1. The chart is moved further down in the div.
2. The chart has no plots or background (although it has axes marks).

According to the developer tools, all canvases are positioned correctly, but they are empty. This is the code used to add new charts (chart_div_? exists):

```
$.jqplot('chart_div_' + chartCounter, sold_plot, {
    seriesColors: [ "#30D2FF", "BFFFCB", "BFFFCB", "BFFFCB" ],
    seriesDefaults: {
        showMarker: false,
        markerOptions: {
            show: false,
        }
    },
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
            min: plot_min,
            max: plot_max,
        }
    },
    grid: {
        background: '#444444',
    },
});
chartCounter++;
```

Could it be something to do with moving a canvas? I tried redrawing it, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the example which can help you: [Jsfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/PXTLM/1/)

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="chart1" style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:20px;"></div>
</div> 
<a href="#" class="topopup">Click Here Trigger</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
    var chartData = [
        ["19-Jan-2012", 2.61],
        ["20-Jan-2012", 5.00],
        ["21-Jan-2012", 6.00]
    ];
    var cnt = 1;
    // add a custom tick formatter, so that you don't have to include the entire date renderer library.
    $.jqplot.DateTickFormatter = function (format, val) {
        // for some reason, format isn't being passed through properly, so just going to hard code for purpose of this jsfiddle
        val = (new Date(val)).getTime();
        format = '%b&nbsp%#d'
        return $.jsDate.strftime(val, format);
    };

    function PlotChart(chartData, extraDays, elem) {

        var plot2 = $.jqplot(elem, [chartData], {
            title: 'Mouse Cursor Tracking',
            seriesDefaults: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                rendererOptions: {
                    barPadding: 1,
                    barWidth: 50
                },
                pointLabels: {
                    show: true
                }
            },
            axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    pad: 1,
                    // a factor multiplied by the data range on the axis to give the            
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                    // renderer to use to draw the axis,     
                    tickOptions: {
                        formatString: '%b %#d',
                        formatter: $.jqplot.DateTickFormatter
                    }
                },
                yaxis: {
                    tickOptions: {
                        formatString: '$%.2f'
                    }
                }
            },
            highlighter: {
                sizeAdjust: 7.5
            },
            cursor: {
                show: true
            }
        });
    }

    PlotChart(chartData, 3, "chart1");


    $("a.topopup").click(function () {
        loading();
        return false;
    });



    function loading() {
        var div = $("#main");
        cnt = cnt + 1;
        var elemId = "chart" + cnt;
        div.prepend("<div id='" + elemId + "'></div>");
        PlotChart(chartData, 3, elemId);
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for me too if I use div.append(data). The thing is I want it to appear in the beginning of the content div and push the old one down, so I do this by div.html(data + div.html()), in which case all other charts but the newest one become empty.

Comment: i have updated the answer to take into consideration your scenario. It works fine for me.

Comment: Awesome! Somehow I did not know about the prepend function. While div.html(data + div.html()) breaks the charts, div.prepend(data) doesn't. Thanks a lot!